# Creation of registration form . input type file returning a null value in the database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

In my registration form all the entered values in the form is getting saved in the database except the input type=file . It returns a null value i.e "0" in the database. Even though a path name is being entered by choosing a file of the desktop. I wanted to know where ive gone wrong, since its returning 0. is it a problem with the database ive created or my code
heres my code for reference:

php code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $course = $_POST['course'];
    $semester = $_POST['semester'];
    $DOB = $_POST['DOB'];
    $gender = $_POST['sex'];

    $file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email_id = $_POST['email_id'];
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_detail(firstname,lastname,course,semester,DOB,gender,registernumber,password,email_id) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")) 
    {
          $stmt->bind_param('ssssssiss',
                            $firstname,$lastname,
                            $course,$semester,$DOB,
                            $gender,$file,$password,$email_id);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            echo $result;
    } else {
        echo "error with insertion";
    }
} 


$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
  && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
  && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) 
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
    {
         echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) 
        {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } else {
             move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                               "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

             echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please enter the following details:</legend>

        <div>
            First Name
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" />
        </div>

        <div>
            Last Name
            <br>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" />
        </div>

        <div>
            Course
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="course">
            </div>

        <div>
            Semester :
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="semester" >
        </div>

        <div>
            Age:
            <br>
            <input type="date" name="DOB">
        </div>

        <div>
            Gender
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value ="male" checked>Male
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value ="female">Female
        </div>
            <br>

        <div>
            Upload Choice of Identity Verification
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="80">

        </div>
            <br>

        <div>
            Password
            <br>
                <input type="password" name="password" />
        </div>

        <div>
            Email-ID
            <br>
                <input type="email" name="email_id" />
        </div> 

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </fieldset>    
    </form>
```

Comment: You are storing data about this file upload in the database BEFORE you have checked that the file was a) uploaded b) uploaded without errors. Could that be part of your problem??

Comment: What EXACTLY do you mean by _it returns a null value_ WHAT VALUE is NULL. Please specify EXACTLY what is NULL

Answer (score 0):

You did not using print_r($_FILES); to check file content is coming or not.

use below code:-

```
<pre>
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //echo ""; // here pre tag will come in double quotes.
    //print_r($_POST);  // show post data
    //print_r($_FILES);  // show files data
    //die; // die to stop execution. 
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $course = $_POST['course'];
    $semester = $_POST['semester'];
    $DOB = $_POST['DOB'];
    $gender = $_POST['sex'];
</code>
    $file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email_id = $_POST['email_id'];
    if($stmt =$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_detail(firstname,lastname,course,semester,DOB,gender,registernumber,password,email_id) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssssiss',$firstname,$lastname,$course,$semester,$DOB,$gender,$file,$password,$email_id);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        echo $result;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error with insertion";
    }
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                    "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid file";
}
}
</pre>
```

Comment: this is what im getting after printing =1 Invalid fileArray ( [firstname] => dgd [lastname] => dd [course] => dg [semester] => gdg [DOB] => 2015-08-07 [sex] => male [password] => fsf [email_id] => rithi_shetty@gmail.com [submit] => Send ) Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => er (1).png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpB7B4.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 114678 ) )

Comment: i dont know why the output is null

Comment: where is problem, you have post and files data. you can save it in db.

Comment: yeah thats my problem . its returning a null value in the database ?                Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => er (1).png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpB7B4.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 114678 ) )

Comment: i gave you answer which you asked, i did not connect with database.